# ambethia's reCAPTCHA plugin on Rails 3. Override flash message div defaults?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, ruby-on-rails-plugins, recaptcha

I have ambethia's reCAPTCHA plugin on Rails 3 working. Does anyone know how to override it's flash message markup? I'd like to reuse my own `flash_error` div id instead of using the plugin's `flash_recaptcha_error` div id:

```
<div id="flash_recaptcha_error">incorrect-captcha-sol</div>
```

Also, how would you clean up this controller#create?

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  respond_to do |format|
    if verify_recaptcha(:model => @post, :error => "reCAPTCHA incorrect. Try again.") && @post.save
      flash.now[:notice] = "Created \"#{@post.title}\""
      format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Incorrect word verification. Are you sure you\'re human?"
      format.html { redirect_to(:back, :error => 'reCAPTCHA incorrect. Try again.') }
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because flash[] is an array you could delete element inside it. When we use recaptcha gem, the flash array contain **recaptcha_error** element, so you just only delete this element with :
**flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)** inside your controller.

For example :

```
if  verify_recaptcha(:model=>@object,:message=>"Verification code is wrong", :attribute=>"verification code") && @object.save
  #your code if succes
else
  flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
  #your code if its fail
end
```

Maybe it could help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a User Authentication System from scratch, you may have to do something like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    respond_to do |format|
        if verify_recaptcha(:model => @user )
            if @user.save
                format.html { redirect_to root_url,  :notice => "You have Signed up!" }
            else
                format.html { render :new }
            end
        else
            flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
            format.html { redirect_to( root_path , :flash => { :error => 'Please retry the two words of the reCaptcha' } ) }
        end
    end
  end
end
```